# error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::RenderWindow::draw(Map (&)())’ | c++

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, sfml

I'm using SFML on Linux, and I'm trying to draw a class name `Map` it has `public: sf::Drawable`, But when I try and do `window.draw(map)` I get

```
src/Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/Main.cpp:30:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::RenderWindow::draw(Map (&)())’
   30 |   window.draw(map);
```

Also tried making the draw function public, and calling it, but still got same error.

[Full Code](https://github.com/PizzaRules668/Alien-Escape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defined Map as `Map map();` Fix was defining it as `Map map;`